# Where can I find a good freelance system administrator?

Tags: hosting

I work developing web-based systems so I know my way around Linux setup to get by, but my projects are increasingly complex.

It seems like a great idea to find someone with hardcore skills in setting up a rock-solid web-hosting box.

Where can I find a good freelance system administrator?

There are a number of sites for outsourcing in the design/code worlds. Are there reputable sites for system administrators?

What should I expect to pay?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you check around for local user-groups.  There are many groups like Linux user groups, where geeks wiil go to learn, share, and network.  Find the closest user group of geeks, even if they don't advertise themselves as system administrators and start there.

The price you pay obviously will depend heavily, on what level of help you need, and where you are located.

Answer (score 2):

You could post a job offer on **[jobs.serverfault.com](http://jobs.serverfault.com/)** (read the [FAQ](http://jobs.serverfault.com/default.asp?pg=pgFAQ) for further details.)

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise there was a job board here.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try [this website](https://serverfault.com/).

;)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, no easy answer.

Good quality, collaborative sysadmins are usually busy. 
I do not know of a good online place to find quality sysadmin folks.
Expect to pay $75/hour for decent folks, IMHO.

Comment: Bit low, since it'll cost you twice that to get a kid from Best Buy to show up, before even touching/fixing something. ;) Poster's an Aussie anyway, so I'm in the dark.